# When posting a shipment, will the payment be captured?

Tags: api, payment, shipment, authorize.net

When posting a shipment for an order using the Magento API, will the payment be captured?

Assume the following is true in this scenario:

1. Authorize.net is being used to process payments
2. Authorize.net is configured to `Authorize Only` as it's Payment Action
3. An order is placed using Authorize.net
4. A shipment is posted through the Magento API for this order

Does it matter if the entire order is shipped? Or if the shipment is only for part of the order?

Comment: I didn't try it, but theoretically NO. Shipment and Invoice has nothing to do with each other. And Payment is part of the invoice stuff.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. Write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and the answer is no. I tested it with my Authorize.net account.

When you process the shipment, partial or not, nothing dealing with payment happens. When you invoice the order, it gives you the option to capture the payment online or offline.

Also, this is very simple to test, even if you don't have a live Authorize.net account to put in test mode and use, you can simply setup a developer account which will give you a sandbox setup to test anything you'd like on.

https://developer.authorize.net/sandbox/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it, but theoretically NO. Shipment and Invoice has nothing to do with each other. And Payment is part of the invoice stuff.

Comment: I understand the distinction, but can you augment this answer with references to code, documentation or your own testing?